# open browser plugin using access vba

Tags: vba, google-chrome, ms-access, browser

i have a plugin installed in chrome browser.it shows star at top right of my browser when click that star it opens the window have some data. i want to write a program using ACCESS vba that will click the link n get data. the window does not have any source code provided.

please help me any thing that solve this issue is welcome.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Access cannot control PC outside it's purview.

I suggest, you use Scripting language to achieve your desired results.